# Can I play online without PlayStation Plus?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, playstation-plus

**Can I play Minecraft online without PlayStation Plus?**

If yes, is there a free option to do so? (It might as well be a server)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible. For all games is the same rule - multiplayer is available only for PlayStation Plus Subscribers. Even in games like Fallout 76, which has an only multiplayer mode.

EDIT: As some people mentioned in the comments below, free play games allow you to play multiplayer without a subscription.

Comment: Both Fortnite and Rocket league can be played without PlayStation+, so I know some games can be played online without it and it does claim on the game that Minecraft servers can be payed online if you sign in with Microsoft but I am not sure weather you need to Microsoft and Ps+.

Comment: @MikeZ. Games that are free-to-play can be played without PS+ online. Minecraft cannot be played online without PS+.

Comment: Wow, that is very important, I did not know about it. Thanks for you for correction of my answer.